# PHP MySQLi - insert_id 0 after insert or update - should I read first?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert-update

I'm still new and some of the right coding practices escape me. Documentation on this particular situation is weak, so I would like to get some advice/suggestions from you experts :) on the following.

I have an API that allows users to update 2 tables in one call. One is a *SUMMARY* table and the other is a *DETAIL* table with an FK to the *SUMMARY* table.

What I have my code doing is I do an UPSERT (insert/update) to the *SUMMARY* table, grab the `insert_id` and then delete the records from the *DETAIL* table, then insert the ones I need (referencing *SUMMARY* with the fk of course).

However, in the instance that there are no changes to SUMMARY data - `insert_id` returns `0`. This seems expected as no row was updated/inserted.

So here is my question:

Should I be doing a full read of the tables and comparing data prior to this update/delete/insert attempt? Or is there another nifty way of grabbing the `id` of the *SUMMARY* that was a duplicate of the UPSERT attempt? I feel that my users will 'almost' ALWAYS be changing the *SUMMARY* and *DETAIL* data when using this API.

What is the correct coding practice here? Is the extra read worth it every time? Or should I read only if `insert_id = 0`?

Thoughts? My biggest problem is that I don't know what the magnitude difference of a read vs a write is here - especially since I don't believe the API will be called much without having changed values.

Again my options are:

1. - Read db and compare to see if there is a diff
   - Insert/Update accordingly
2. - Attempt Insert/update.
   - if (insert_id = 0) then read db to get summary id for details table
   - copmlete process
3. - Attempt Insert/Update
   - use ?something? to get id of summary of record that was duplicate (and prevented insert/update)
   - use the id to complete steps.

Comment: Just re-read. Saying that documentation is weak is probably a mistake. However, I'm struggling probably because I don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

If the id you need is an auto_increment field, option 4 (do everything inside DB with 1 execute action) 100% of the time. This is the general SQL structure you need:

`Insert into summary (primaryKey, fieldA, fieldB) values (NULL, valueA, valueB) on duplicate key update primaryKey=LAST_INSERT_ID(primaryKey), fieldA = fieldA, fieldB=fieldB;`

If you then do `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` it'll give you either the successful inserted id or ,if duplicate, the duplicate entrie's id. So do something like:

`delete from detail where summary_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Answer (score 0):

At the companies I've worked for, option 1 is usually the one I've seen used if you're wanting to compare record by record.  This can be implemented either in a stored proc or in the code itself.  Depends on the context of what "same" means.  If it's raw values, then sql is probably the easiest.  If there's a context in addition to what the database has, you'll want to do it at the code level.  Hope that helps.